# List<String> Databind to multiple Textbox on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Hi I have read some tutorials on Data Binding but I can't seem to find what I need which is a DataBinding of a List to a Multiple TextBox.

I'm not sure if this is possible on WPF and I'm quite new to Data Binding so bear with me.

I have a List(Global Variable)
and let say it has 3 words which are "Apple", "Banana" and "Orange" 
this 3 words are given by the Code Behind of my XAML.

In my XAML I have 3 TextBox, from first to third I want to assign my List to it so from the

```
first textbox -> Apple
second textbox -> Banana
third textbox -> Orange
```

Now the catch here is that I need it to work in 2 ways which means for example
I edit the first textbox to "Mango", the List on the Code Behind will also change.

Is this possible on Data Binding?

Comment: Is List fixed at 3?  If so use string[].

Comment: Check out the [PropertyPath XAML Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742451(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN to find out about the different `Binding Path` syntax that you can use.

Answer (score 0):

You can just bind to the element of the list.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FruitList[0]}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FruitList[1]}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FruitList[2]}" />
```

**Edit:**

The default binding method of a TextBox is TwoWay, but you can add this if you want to make it clear.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FruitList[0]} Mode=TwoWay" />
```

You can also add `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to make the List update on every key stroke.

**Edit2:**

To acces the objects gcreated in code behind you have to set tht DataContext of your WPF. See [wpf xaml binding to object created in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981966/wpf-xaml-binding-to-object-created-in-code-behind)

Comment: Your Code "Text="{Binding Path=FruitList[0]} Mode=TwoWay"" Does not work, the Mode=TwoWay has an error. 

How can I declare the FruitList? I tried putting it up on the Global Variable in my code behind but it did not give back any value. 

Should I declare or put something on my XAML?