# MessageBoxButton.YesNo in object

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

The code that I cant get to work:

```
object MessageBoxButton = null;  
if (MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:0,0}", Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)), "OK ??????", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == DialogResult == false)
```

Links to stuff I found/tried:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981966/wpf-xaml-binding-to-object-created-in-code-behind)

[Link2](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=wpf%20object%20messageboxbutton&oq=wpf%20object%20messageboxbutton&aqs=chrome..69i57.9767j0j7)

The error I get:
'object' does not contain a definition for 'YesNo' and no extension method 'YesNo'.

Comment: Everything from the code up and the links down doesn't need to be in the question (at least not for me) . It's created quite a bit of _noise_. I would also look at formatting any code _as code_ using 4 spaces to indent (It tells you how to format on the right (when asking/editing).

Comment: @Jinx88909 I will change it, thanks for the comment

Comment: @Luca Your question is missing the most important information, namely the error you get. if there is a compiler error, include it into the question.

Comment: @NineBerry I eddited it in the question now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you try to declare a local variable named `MessageBoxButton`? This is the name of class that already exists in the framework. If the compiler says that it cannot find the type `MessageBoxButton`, you have to include the namespace where it can be found using a `using` clause at the top of the file:

```
using System.Windows;
```

Then you can just write:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void Demo()
    {
        MessageBoxResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Text", "Caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        if(dialogResult == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Yes was clicked");
        }
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No was clicked");
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the Microsoft Styleguide says not to use `MessageBoxImage.Question`. Only use Information, Warning or Error instead (or no Icon at all).

Answer (score -3):

Try

```
if (MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0:0,0}", Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)), "OK ??????", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
```

Comment: This does not work for me, but still thank you. Maybe it is worth noting te error I get. It says: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'YesNo' and no extension method 'YesNo'. I will also add this in the question.

Comment: Probably a good idea to copy a little bit more of your code into your question as well.  See NineBerry's answer, the namespace may be all you need.

Comment: His anwer realy helped me. I did not know what I was doing since it is written by someone else and I have no experience in WPF.